# SQL/Oracle - adding a userID to a friend table with the name FriendID

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I am currently working on a piece of corusework for an Advanced databases university module using Oracle APEX with Objects. 
We are required to create a facebook like application with a user table and a friend table.
The users table was created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE user_table (
    userId NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    userName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
    emailAddress     VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL, 
    password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(userId)
);
```

The freinds following table:

```
CREATE TABLE friends_following_table(
    friendId NUMBER NOT NULL,
    userId NUMBER references user_table,
    PRIMARY KEY(friend_id )
);
```

My question: 
I am required to have `friends` that are connected to users.
How can the `userId` become a `friendId`? Or have done this completely wrong?

```
Sample user: 
userId: 1 
name: shannon
userId: 2
name: Alison
```

User 1 and user 2 need to be friends and the database needs to reflect this

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example for this "friends' that are connected to users" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on given `user_table` in your question:

```
CREATE TABLE user_table (
userId NUMBER NOT NULL, 
userName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
emailAddress     VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL, 
password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(userId)
);
```

And also based on your sample data and desired output:

> Sample user: userId: 1 name: shannon userId: 2 name: Alison
>
> User 1 and user 2 need to be friends and the database needs to reflect
>   this

In fact you have a **`Many-To-Many`** relationship between users so you need such this table for the relations:

```
CREATE TABLE friends_following_table(
user_id NUMBER REFERENCES user_table,
follower_id NUMBER REFERENCES user_table,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id,follower_id)
);
```

---

In case of your sample data:

```
INSERT INTO user_table 
VALUES(1,'shannon','s@so.com','123');
INSERT INTO user_table 
VALUES(2,'Alison','a@so.com','123');
```

now you have to specify which one follows the other one:

if `user 2` follows `user 1`:

```
INSERT INTO friends_following_table VALUES(1,2);
```

and if `user 1` follows `user 2`:

```
INSERT INTO friends_following_table VALUES(2,1);
```

---

You can extract `every two followers` by a simple `join`:

```
SELECT u1.userId,u1.userName,
       u2.userName "FOLLOWS"
FROM user_table u1
JOIN friends_following_table f on u1.userId=f.follower_id
JOIN user_table u2 on u2.userId=f.user_Id
```

---

you can count the ***number of followers*** of every user by using `count` function with a `left join`:

```
SELECT u.userId,u.userName,
       count(f.follower_id) "FOLLOWERS"
FROM user_table u
LEFT JOIN friends_following_table f on u.userId=f.user_Id
GROUP BY u.userId,u.userName
```

---

you can also count the ***number of followings*** of every user by using `count` function with a `left join`:

```
SELECT u.userId,u.userName,
       count(f.follower_id) "FOLLOWINGS"
FROM user_table u
LEFT JOIN friends_following_table f on u.userId=f.follower_id
GROUP BY u.userId,u.userName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this schema instead:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTable (
  UserID NUMBER NOT NULL
  , UserName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
  , EmailAddress VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL
  , Password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT PK_UserTable PRIMARY KEY(UserID)
);

CREATE TABLE FriendTable (
  UserID NUMBER NOT NULL
  , FriendID NUMBER NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT PK_FriendTable PRIMARY KEY(UserID, FriendID)
  , CONSTRAINT FK_FriendTable_UserID FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES UserTable(UserID)
  , CONSTRAINT FK_FriendTable_FriendID FOREIGN KEY (FriendID) REFERENCES UserTable(UserID)
);
```